# How to change position of Adapter in Android

Tags: android

In my application I want change set new value to position of recyclerview adapter. 
With **java language** I can it with below code:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MonthFragmentAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    position += 6 - (position % 7) * 2;
}
```

But in **kotlin** I can't use below code and show me val error for position.

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    position += 6 - position % 7 * 2
}
```

Show me **Val cannot be reassigned!** I know I can't set new value for val, but how can I change my code for fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    var newPosition = position
    newPosition += 6 - newPosition % 7 * 2
}
```

Use a new variable to change the value.

It is `Kotlin` feature, you can't change the function parameter.

Answer (score 0):

chainging adapter position is not possible, but you can do it with taht way
if (position == yourposition){//do that}